# Issues in launching desktop extension code from UWP app

Tags: wcf, uwp, system-tray, desktop-bridge

I have a requirement to host a WCF service to receive responses from a service. As UWP app doesn’t have wcf hosting capabilities, I chose this system tray component where I will host my service so that I get responses and communicate to UWP app via app service and show toasts.

But the systray component terminates immediately after the launch. To be clear on my systray integration with uwp I already tested it and is working and then extended it with WCF hosting.

Later I tried adding debugs showing message box on exceptions and found out that WCF service open call throwing below exception.

"**System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL http::1234**"

Later understood that the sys tray app requires admin rights to register the URL that is hosted as part of the service and as UWP app launches sys tray via full trust API and it doesn't do through admin elevation.

So to solve this I got 2 approaches and tried as mentioned below:

1)
So I tried adding URL reg manually using netsh and same program works. Just to tweak I tried running the "same netsh command in sys tray app itself with admin priv" and only launched the tray app and i could see no exception and could see my service hosted, checked in browser.

Now I'm stuck with providing admin privileges while launching the sys tray app via UWP app.

But if tray app is launched by UWP, even though I included the netsh command it still shows the same exception. (Might be parent process (as run as admin is N/A UWP apps) is not having admin rights so even my netsh cmd in sys tray app is not working??? )

OR is there any way to provide arguments or any other API to run the tray app with admin via full trust api's from UWP app???

2) 
Tried adding app manifest file to the tray app and modified as below

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

But this also shows a error box saying this requires elevation and exited.

Kindly Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requesting elevated privileges is currently not supported for desktop-bridge processes. So what you are seeing here is currently expected. The good news is that we are adding a new capability in RS5 (Fall 2018 update) called 'allowElevation', which will enable scenarios that require elevation.

You should be able to start testing the new capability with the latest Windows Insider Preview build and the corresponding SDK.

UPDATE 10/1/2018: I have posted a sample for this new capability
https://stefanwick.com/2018/10/01/app-elevation-samples-part-1/

Comment: Approx when would this RS5 official release would happen?

Comment: I'm also facing one more issue while creating appx package for side loading. Appx creation is successful for Debug configuration but shows below errors for Release configuration.

Manifest validation error: Line 29, Column 64, Reason: The file name "SystemTrayExtension.exe" declared for element "*[local-name()='Applications']/*[local-name()='Application']/*[local-name()='Extensions']/*[local-name()='Extension' and @Category='windows.fullTrustProcess']" doesn't exist in the package.

Comment: I found that packaging should be done using separate Packaging project for this scenario, correct me if i'm wrong. I created that project and added uwp and tray app as ref and selected uwp app as entry point.
In my sample on launch of UWP app itself i'm starting the tray app in OnLaunched(). But after installing from above appx created, I couldn't see the tray app in system tray.

Comment: I debugged and made sure that it enters the api contract present but doesn't launch the tray app. I also observed similar when trying to launch from VS and it shows the tray app .exe not found. For debug configuration it takes care of this .exe but in release config VS isn't finding the .exe in bin/x64/Release/Appx. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The release is targeted for October 2018. Make sure you set the startup project correctly in the sample. For new questions/problems please start a new question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Just to not miss the context in complete sense and as it is related to same scenario i'm extending here itself. I actually set the startup project properly as UWP app and on launch of UWP app it should launch tray app. But it is not happening.

Comment: If you are using my sample, it will only launch the tray app after you close the UWP and select the "Systray" option. If you want to launch the systray right away you will need to move the call to FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync.

Comment: Yes I'm saying that only.. as UWP app launches in OnLaunched() method I'm calling this above FullTrust API, but it works when I run from VS only for Debug Config and not for Release config. Also it doesn't work for both configs Appx packages. I kept UWP app set as entry point in the packaging project, so that my UWP launches first and then it calls my full trust api in OnLaunched(). But it's not launching in actual. So couldn't figure out.

Comment: First thing I would do is look at this simple sample and figure out what you are doing differently in your project: https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/ 

If it still doesn't work, start a new question on SO and share a repro project.